# How to use a global pipeline library when defining an Active Choices Reactive Parameter?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way to use a global pipeline library when defining an *Active Choices Reactive Parameter* in Jenkins?

I have added a global pipeline library in Jenkins, let's say `PipelineLibrary`, and I am able to use it successfully in my pipelines by loading it with `@Library('PipelineLibrary') _`. In this library I have a global function `foo.bar()`, which I would like to use also in the Groovy Script box when adding an *Active Choices Reactive Parameter* to several of my jobs.

So I would like to have something like this in the Groovy Script box of that parameter:

```
// Somehow take into use PipelineLibrary
return foo.bar();
```

What is the correct syntax to load the library here?
Or is it even possible? If not, is there some other way to share the Groovy script to several places without just copy-pasting the code in the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're banging on this door - [JENKINS-46394](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-46394)

Comment: Yes, seems to be the correct door. Thank you for the link!
So looks like it is currently not possible, but people have been asking about it for five years. So not holding my breath on having it implemented any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have found a way to do it. You just need to need to define new global variables in your Jenkinsfile and their values will be from the Shared library respectfully. Afterwards you can use the new defined global variables in your Active Choice Parameter script.

Comment: Do you have an example?